# Get JSON Array and add items to Combobox in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi, combobox

I have this JSON data:

```json
[
  {
    "Name":"val1",
    "Age":"25"
  },
  {
    "Name":"Vtya",
    "Age":"24"
  },
  {
    "Name":"fgani",
    "Age":"21"
  },
  {
    "Name":"Shami",
    "Age":"21"
  },
  {
    "Name":"Slakf",
    "Age":"22"
  }
]
```

I wrote this code to parse the data and add the `Name` value to a Combobox:

```pascal
procedure TJSON_Sample.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LJsonArray: TJSONArray;
  LJsonValue, LITEM: TJSONValue;
  lJsonData: string;
  ljsPair: TJsonPair;
begin
  LJsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.
    Default.GetBytes(lJsonData), 0) as TJSONArray;//lJsonData contains the above mentioned JSON data
  try
    for LJsonValue in LJsonArray do
    begin
      for LITEM in TJSONArray(LJsonValue) do
      begin
        cmbBox_Name.Items.Add(TJsonPair(LITEM).JsonValue.Value);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    LJsonArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When I run this, it is adding all of the Names and Ages to the Combobox.  Can someone please help me in adding the Names only?

Comment: I'd also say that your use of unchecked casts means that your code will behave in an undefined manner if it encounters data with incorrect form. You need to be using is and as operators for checked type testing and conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Solved my request

```
procedure TJSON_Sample.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LITEM, lJsonValue: TJSONValue;
  lJsonData: string;
begin
  lJsonValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.
    Default.GetBytes(lJsonData), 0);//lJsonData contains the above mentioned JSON data
  if lJsonValue <> nil then
    try
      begin
        for LITEM in lJsonValue as TJSONArray do
        begin
          cmbBox_Name.Items.Add(((LITEM as TJSONObject).Get('Name') .JsonValue as TJSONString).Value);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      lJsonValue.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is looping fine through your JSON. Your problem is to get just the 'Name' value when adding the item to the combobox.

Try GetValue('Name') instead of the whole JSONValue.Value.

```
procedure TJSON_Sample.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LJsonArray: TJSONArray;
  LJsonValue, LITEM: TJSONValue;
  lJsonData: string;
  ljsPair: TJsonPair;
begin
  LJsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.
    Default.GetBytes(lJsonData), 0) as TJSONArray;//lJsonData contains the above mentioned JSON data
  try
    for LJsonValue in LJsonArray do
    begin
      for LITEM in TJSONArray(LJsonValue) do
      begin
        cmbBox_Name.Items.Add(TJsonObject(LITEM).GetValue('Name').Tostring);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    LJsonArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `cmbBox_Name.Items.Add(TJsonObject(LITEM).GetValue('Name').Tostring);` this statement is getting list of Names and adding to ComboBox, but the double quotes are still left and also the statement should be appended with `.Tostring` at end then only code executes else it gives Invalid types error.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote it from memory. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using the [`Items.AddObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.TStrings.AddObject) method instead, and use `Items.Object[ComboBox1.ItemIndex]` on the OnChange event of the combo-box.

Answer (score 0):

Here is almost the same code, but I add `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` for combobox items and use generic methods to avoid type casting.

```
procedure TJSON_Sample.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LJson, LItem: TJSONValue;
  lJsonData: string;
begin
  cmbBox_Name.Items.BeginUpdate;
  try
    cmbBox_Name.Items.Clear;

    LJson := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.
      Default.GetBytes(lJsonData), 0);//lJsonData contains the above mentioned JSON data

    if Assigned(LJson) then
    begin
      for LItem in LJson as TJSONArray do
        cmbBox_Name.Items.Add(LItem.GetValue<string>('Name'));
    end;
  finally
    cmbBox_Name.Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```